# Kibana Visualization based on multiple fields

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, visualization, kibana, elastic-stack

Been searching for a day or two on how to do this, really hoping someone can help...

I want to create a visualization based on two fields.
Fields are:
**Name**
**Activity**

Name could have a string value of around 200 different names.
Activity has only two possible string values - '**increase**' & '**decrease**'.

What I want to do is visualize a count of the amounts of increases & decreases overlapping for each name on a bar chart.
Is this possible?

E.g. Say the name 'Bob_Jones' pops up in my log five times & one has an increase value, but four have a decrease value. How can I visualize that particular name on a bar chart with both the count of increase & decrease values overlapping on the chart?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use Visualize.
On the left, leave `Y-Axis` as it is. On `X-Axis` remove everything you already have: you should find yourself in the following situation:

[image: First step]

press on `Split Bars`. Now select `Terms` in the `Aggregation` dropdown. In the `Field` choose `Activity` on the dropdown (the name of your field).

Now you have to press on the button in the bottom of the screen, called `Add sub-buckets`. Choose `X-Axis`, put as `Sub Aggregation` the value `Terms` once again, and in the `Field` choose `Name`.

Now, if you press the "Play" button (check the pic I uploaded, in the top-right) you should have what you are looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Andrea. I did try to look at Timelion at the weekend but the syntax for a complete newb is difficult to get your head around. How would you place the fields on a graph as described above? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Timelion is not the correct way. I didn't read well your question, sorry it was my mistake. I updated my answer using Visualize: tell me if it works for you.

Comment: That's sorted it, thanks Andrea. FYI I don't have a 'Split Bars' but I do have a 'Split Series' which seems to offer what I need. Not sure if this is down to my version of Kibana (5.4.0).

Comment: You are welcome, I'm glad I helped you! Thanks for pointing out that little detail. My version is the 5.2.2, maybe something changed in between :)